# Plotting data with time variable in R

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot the below shown data. There are at least 16 hrs of data for each ID and these can be grouped by severity. Is there a better way to do this, please?

```
ID                TIME           SEVERITY
00-00-0C-12-43-02 2/21/2015 0:00 GOOD
00-00-0C-12-43-02 2/21/2015 1:00 GOOD
00-00-0C-12-43-02 2/21/2015 2:00 CRASH
00-00-0C-12-43-02 2/21/2015 3:00 CRASH
00-00-0C-12-43-02 2/21/2015 4:00 ERROR
00-00-0C-12-43-02 2/21/2015 5:00 WARN
00-00-0C-12-43-02 2/21/2015 6:00 GOOD
00-00-0C-12-43-02 2/21/2015 7:00 CRASH
00-00-0C-12-43-02 2/21/2015 8:00 GOOD
00-00-0C-12-43-02 2/21/2015 9:00 GOOD
00-00-0C-12-43-02 2/21/2015 10:00 GOOD
00-00-0C-12-43-02 2/21/2015 11:00 GOOD
00-00-0C-12-43-02 2/21/2015 12:00 GOOD
00-00-0C-12-43-02 2/21/2015 13:00 ERROR
00-00-0C-12-43-02 2/21/2015 14:00 ERROR
00-00-0C-12-43-02 2/21/2015 15:00 GOOD
00-00-0C-12-43-02 2/21/2015 16:00 GOOD
00-03-E0-43-11-19 2/21/2015 0:00 GOOD
00-03-E0-43-11-19 2/21/2015 1:00 GOOD
00-03-E0-43-11-19 2/21/2015 2:00 CRASH
00-03-E0-43-11-19 2/21/2015 3:00 ERROR
00-03-E0-43-11-19 2/21/2015 4:00 GOOD
00-03-E0-43-11-19 2/21/2015 5:00 ERROR
00-03-E0-43-11-19 2/21/2015 6:00 ERROR
00-03-E0-43-11-19 2/21/2015 7:00 GOOD
00-03-E0-43-11-19 2/21/2015 8:00 GOOD
00-03-E0-43-11-19 2/21/2015 9:00 GOOD
00-03-E0-43-11-19 2/21/2015 10:00 GOOD
00-03-E0-43-11-19 2/21/2015 11:00 GOOD
00-03-E0-43-11-19 2/21/2015 12:00 GOOD
00-03-E0-43-11-19 2/21/2015 13:00 ERROR
00-03-E0-43-11-19 2/21/2015 14:00 GOOD
00-03-E0-43-11-19 2/21/2015 15:00 GOOD
00-03-E0-43-11-19 2/21/2015 16:00 ERROR
```

I am able to get the ID and Severity column in plot as below,

```
tsb <- table(plot_data[,1],plot_data[,3]) 
plot(tsb,col=c("red","yellow","green","pink"),
  main="Status for Last 17 hrs")
```

Wanted to include the Time column.
Tried this,

```
tsb <- table(plot_data[,1],order(plot_data[,2]),plot_data[,3]),
```

but the plot doesn't look very much OK because of the data in y axis, and getting some dark lines in between each hour data. Is there a right/better way to get a clear view of this data on plot. I am very new to R, learning from few days....

Comment: Better than ... what?

Comment: Write the code you used for input. Show what you tried for converting to dates.  Describe what you want to see in greater detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
ddf = structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("00-00-0C-12-43-02", 
"00-03-E0-43-11-19"), class = "factor"), DATE = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = "2/21/2015", class = "factor"), TIME = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L), .Label = c("0:00", "1:00", "10:00", "11:00", 
"12:00", "13:00", "14:00", "15:00", "16:00", "2:00", "3:00", 
"4:00", "5:00", "6:00", "7:00", "8:00", "9:00"), class = "factor"), 
    SEVERITY = structure(c(3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("CRASH", 
    "ERROR", "GOOD", "WARN"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", 
"DATE", "TIME", "SEVERITY"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-34L))

levels(ddf$SEVERITY) = c("CRASH","ERROR","WARN","GOOD")

ss = strsplit(as.character(ddf$TIME), ':')

for(i in 1:length(ss)) (ddf$newtime[i]=ss[[i]][1])

head(ddf)
                 ID      DATE TIME SEVERITY newtime
1 00-00-0C-12-43-02 2/21/2015 0:00     GOOD       0
2 00-00-0C-12-43-02 2/21/2015 1:00     GOOD       1
3 00-00-0C-12-43-02 2/21/2015 2:00    CRASH       2
4 00-00-0C-12-43-02 2/21/2015 3:00    CRASH       3
5 00-00-0C-12-43-02 2/21/2015 4:00    ERROR       4
6 00-00-0C-12-43-02 2/21/2015 5:00     WARN       5


ggplot(ddf, aes(x=as.numeric(newtime), y=SEVERITY, group=ID, color=ID))+geom_line()+geom_point()
```

[image]

EDIT: 
For a barchart:

```
ggplot(ddf) + geom_bar(aes(x=as.numeric(newtime), y=SEVERITY, group=ID, fill=ID), stat="identity",position="dodge")
```

[image]

Comment: This looks more meaningful, however when i am going to have more values in ID, it gets difficlut to understand the plot..can we have some kind of bar/stack instead of lines. Also I am getting an error while splitting the TIME value and having a new time value. Error in seq.default(from = best$lmin, to = best$lmax, by = best$lstep) : 'from' must be of length 1In addition: Warning messages:
1: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : NAs introduced by coercion

Comment: Hi, Thanks !! I got it working and managed to change the geom for more IDs!